# VFP - Installshield Wizard Interrupted

Tags: installshield, foxpro, visual-foxpro

This will be vague and I apologize in advance.  I've been using the Install Shield Express for the past 7 years now without any issues; except for now and only 1 computer.

The client is running Windows XP (and yes I've talked with him about updating), once the wizard starts to run, it starts and then gives him the message 'The wizard has been interrupted' and quits during the install and the program doesn't get installed.

I've had him stop his AVG anti-virus, setup a unique user but the same thing keeps occurring. As I said, since I've been working with him these past two weeks, I've had 5 other customers buy the software install it and there's no problems.

I'm  at a loss at what to look for.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This is really an Installshield question to be honest.

Comment: Thought I had tagged it with installshield also.  since it's a program written in VFP 9, thought if anyone else had this type of issue, they might have an idea that could help.

Comment: I can't remember what version of ISE it was but certainly with current versions of the full Installshield you can run the setup with command line flags to make it produce a verbose log file. That's the first thing I would do.

Answer (score 0):

What does the install log tell you? here is the command to install a package and generate a log:
msiexec /i YourPacakge.msi /lvx* %temp%\install.log

after the install fails open the log file in the temp folder. Search for "return value 3" to see which action failed.  Hopefully that will lead you to the root cause.

Comment: Client is cleaning out his machine now, once he's done I'll try generating the log.